# How to erase a type of instance when serializing/deserializing JSON?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, fasterxml

I use `fasterxml` to serialize/deserialize JSON

```
public class A {
    String field;
    B b;
}

public class B {
    int n;
}
```

I want to get a JSON in format like this

```
{
  "field": "abc",
  "n": 123
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `@JsonUnwrapped`. No custom serializers are needed:

```
public class A {
    public String field;
    @JsonUnwrapped
    public B b;
}

public class B {
    public int n;
}
```

Pay attention to the fields accessibility or it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jackson annotation to provide a specific deserializer.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ADeserializer.class)
public class A {

    private String field;
    private B b;

    // ...
}
```

A deserializer for your type should be like this

```
public class ADeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<A> {

    @Override
    public A deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec codec = p.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = codec.readTree(p);

        String field = node.get("field").asText();
        int n = node.get("n").asInt();

        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        b.setN(n);

        a.setField(field);
        a.setB(b);

        return a;
    }

}
```

For serialization it's possible to use custom Serializer. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that in Java.

Comment: As Alex demonstrates in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41775176/466862) it is possible.